# How to associate user to news?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to link each news with some particular user.
I linked comments to particular news, but this doesn't work

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@user , @user.newss.build]) do |form| %>
  <%# if news.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%#= pluralize(news.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this 
news from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <%# news.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%#= message %></li>
      <%# end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <%# end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :news
end
#my news.rb
class News < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user
end
```

It shows different kind of errors I can't understand that...

Comment: What your done is correct. Can i know the error?

Comment: okay wait i m d

Comment: undefined method `user_news_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000d0611e0>:0x000000000d05ac28>
Did you mean?  user_session_path

Comment: Show your controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend doing this at controller level, if you have a user logged in and you have a news controller initiate news object and create object like below,

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @news = News.new #place this inside your form 
  end

  def create
   @news = current_user.news.create permit_params
   if @news.errors.blank?
    # Redirect or concerned logic here
   else
    # Rerender errors to the form
   end
  end

  private
  def permit_params
     params.require(:news).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

This will make sure only the news is binded to the user who is creating it otherwise the for will be passing user_id that is an exposed vulnerability. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails follows the convention over configuration that means you just need to follow proper conventions to get proper result.

For Example:

Here News belongs to user and user has many news
so to fetch news of particular user you will do **user.news** and for news you will do **news.user**

Here we use the plural of news while the singular form of user

So in your code you just made a little convention mistake in your form for.

Just remove extra 's' from newss in your following code.

```
<%= form_for([@user , @user.newss.build]) do |form| %>
```

this has to be:

```
<%= form_for([@user , @user.news.build]) do |form| %>
```

Comment: undefined method `user_news_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000d0611e0>:0x000000000d05ac28>
Did you mean?  user_session_path it still shows this error and not working